# Working with Pagination Response from REST API

Tags: python-3.x, rest, api, pagination, python-requests

Using requests lib to make api calls to an endpoint. How do I iterate over the paginated data?

```
url = 'api/table/incidents'
r = requests.get(url, params=None).json()

{'limit': '20',
 'next': '/api/table/incidents?pagination=2',
 'prev': '/api/table/incidents?pagination=1',
 'total': '5'}
```

I do not want to make repeated calls to the endpoint. Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: You can use a for loop to mae the calls. 
Try this: 
page = range(1,number of pages)
for page in range(1,number_of page):
      url = '/api/table/incidents?pagination=' + str(page)
      r = requests.get(url, params=None).json()
     #perform other operations as need

Comment: Thanks @AnubhavSingh. Did it for me!